# Why this intuition about natural transformations corresponds to its formal definition?

Tags: category-theory, intuition

Almost everywhere people introduce the notion of natural transformations between two functors  $ F$, $ G$ : $ \textbf C \Rightarrow \textbf D$ by examples like what follows:

This is the *intuition* they approach with:

- Consider for example, the functors $(- \times  B) \times 
      C$ and  $- \times ( B \times  C): \textbf C 
     \Rightarrow \textbf C$. For an object $\mathcal A$ we have the 
  isomorphism $(A \times B) \times C 
     \cong^{h_A} A \times ( B \times 
     C)$  via $h_ A$.   *Now if we change* $ A$ into
  $\mathcal  A'$, we still have a similar isomorphism  $( A'
     \times  B) \times C \cong^{h_{A'}}
      A'  \times ( B \times  C)$ via some morphism
  $h_ {A'}$. That is, the isomorphism holds independent of
  the choice of  $ A$. That is the idea of a natural transformation.

Now as they say, *this can be formalized* by the fact that:

- For any morphism $f: A \to  A'$, the following
  diagram  commutes:

[image]

> Now, I don't get how that "substitution/change and holding a similar
>    isomorphism" is taken from "existing a morphism $f:A \to
>  A'$ and commuting the diagram"!

HINT: I'm not concerned about the so called *isomorphism* between those objects; let it be a simple morphism (as in the general case of a natural transformation) if you want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The formalization of

> - Consider for example, the functors $(- \times  B) \times 
>       C$ and  $- \times ( B \times  C): \textbf C 
>      \Rightarrow \textbf C$. For an object $\mathcal A$ we have the 
>     isomorphism $(A \times B) \times C 
>      \cong^{h_A} A \times ( B \times 
>      C)$  via $h_ A$.   *Now if we change* $ A$ into
>     $\mathcal  A'$, we still have a similar isomorphism  $( A'
>      \times  B) \times C \cong^{h_{A'}}
>       A'  \times ( B \times  C)$ via some morphism
>     $h_ {A'}$. That is, the isomorphism holds independent of
>     the choice of  $ A$. That is the idea of a natural transformation.

is not a natural transformation, but merely the family of (iso)morphisms $(A\times B)\times C\cong^{h_A}A\times(B\times C)$. Notice that as a family, the morphisms $h_A$ are indexed by the *objects* $A$ of the category. More generally, the above intuition is only enough to explain why given two functors $F,G\colon\mathbf C\to\mathbf D$, we would want a family of morphisms $FX\xrightarrow{h_X}GX$ indexed by the objects $X$ of $\mathbf C$.

What is missing from the above intuition is exactly the *naturality* of the natural transformation, that is, the requirement that the family of morphisms be in addition *compatible* with the morphisms of $\mathbf C$ in an appropriate way. Thus I would say that the above intuition does not really capture the essential feature of a natural transformation, namely its naturality.

Now, intuition is necessarily a personal tool, so I can only give you my own thoughts, which are two.

First, consider not categories in general, but locally small categories. That is, consider a category $\mathbf C$ such that for each pair of objects $X$ and $Y$ the associated collection of morphisms is the collection of elements of a set $Hom_{\mathbf C}(X,Y)$, and such that the composition relation between morphisms is captured by a set function $Hom(Y,Z)_{\mathbf C}\times Hom(X,Y)_{\mathbf C}\xrightarrow{\circ}Hom_{\mathbf C}(X,Z)$.

Then each object $X$ determines an actual functor $Hom_{\mathbf C}(X,-)\colon\mathbf C\to\mathbf Set$ sending each object $Y$ of $\mathbf C$ to the set $Hom_{\mathbf C}(X,Y)$ and each morphism $Y_1\xrightarrow{h}Y_2$ in $\mathbf C$ to the post-composition function between sets $Hom_{\mathbf C}(X,Y_1)\xrightarrow{Hom_{\mathbf C}(X,h)}Hom_{\mathbf C}(X,Y_2)$ sending a morphism $X\xrightarrow{g}Y_1$ to its post-composition $X\xrightarrow{g}Y_1\xrightarrow{g}Y_2$ with $h$. In other words, $h_*^X(h)=h\circ g$. Such functors are called *representable*.

A natural question arises, which is this: what relationship between the functors $Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_2,-)$ and $Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_1,-)$ is induced by a morphism $X_2\xrightarrow{f}X_1$?

The answer is that any morphism $X_2\xrightarrow{f} X_1$ induces a pre-composition function of sets $Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_2,Y)\xleftarrow{f^*_Y}Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_1,Y)$, one for each object $Y$ in $\mathbf C$. So in particular we have a family of functions of sets $f^*_Y$ indexed by the objects $Y$ of $\mathbf C$, just as your paragraph suggests. But this family is also compatible in a very specific way with the morphisms in $\mathbf C$. Namely, associativity of composition $(f\circ g)\circ h=f\circ (g\circ h)$ is equivalently expressed by the statement that the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_2,Y_1) @>{Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_2,h)}>> Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_2,Y_2)\\
@V{f^*_{Y_2}}VV @V{f^*_{Y_1}}VV \\
Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_1,Y_1) @>{Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_2,h)}>> Hom_{\mathbf C}(X_1,Y_2)
\end{CD}$$
commutes. In this case, naturality of the family of morphisms amounts exactly to associativity. (If one takes a further small step in this direction and asks what are the natural transformations from $Hom_{\mathbf C}(X,-)$ to any functor $\mathbf C\to\mathbf Set$, you would discover the Yoneda lemma, and in particular that the opposite category $\mathbf C^{op}$ of $\mathbf C$ is exactly the category of representable functors and natural transformations between them).

A second way to intuitively grasp the naturality of natural transformations is to view a functor $\mathbf C\xrightarrow{F}\mathbf D$ as a *structured family* of objects of $\mathbf D$ indexed by the objects of $\mathbf C$, the structure specified by the family of morphisms of $\mathbf D$, indexed by the morphisms of $\mathbf C$, between the objects in the structured family of objects of $\mathbf D$. From this point of view, a natural transformation between two functors is a homomorphism between the two structured families of objects. The most common case of this are algebraically structured sets, e.g. groups. A set with a binary operation $M$ can be thought of as the family of sets $\{e\},M,M\times M,M\times M\times M,\dots$ with structure given by the iterated binary multiplications: $M\times M\xrightarrow{\mu} M$ sending $(m_1,m_2)\mapsto m_1\cdot m_2$, $M\times M\times M\to M$ sending $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ to $(m_1\cdot m_2)\cdot m_3$ or $m_1\cdot(m_2\cdot m_3)$, etc. Then a set function $M_1\xrightarrow{f} M_2$ determines a family of morphisms $M_1^n\xrightarrow{(f,f,\dots,f)}M_2^n$, and naturality of that family will be exactly the statement that $f$ is a homomorphism of the binary operation.

Comment: I think you've given the intuition slightly short shrift-you seem to ignore the idea that it should be somehow *the same* isomorphism no matter which objects we've chosen. I think this really is the exact vague intuition for which naturality is meant to give an objective correlate.

Comment: @KevinCarlson you mean the intuition I did present is 1- The intuition behind it. 2- and it is vague intuition?

Comment: @Amir.HKiani yes. That's not to insult it-most intuitions are vague.